# How to print data from SQL database to HTML table based on query

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

so I have records in my database that I would like to print to a HTML table IF they belong to the user.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_name." WHERE Username='".$username."'";
```

The table would read :

Date, Room, Period , Cancel

With cancel being a red cross designed to delete that specific entry from the database :

Booking ID, Date, Period,Type,RoomID, Username are the fields in the database.

How would I go about doing this? I was thinking echoing a table using a for loop but I wouldn't know where to begin?

Comment: you should begin with google.

Comment: Try this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: There are plenty tutorials on this. If you just search for PHP/MySQL Tutorial on Google/Youtube/DuckDuckGo/etc, you will find what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$query_rsSearch = "SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_name." WHERE Username='".$username."'";
$rsSearch = mysql_query($query_rsSearch) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsSearch = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSearch);
$totalRows_rsSearch = mysql_num_rows($rsSearch);

do {
   echo $row_rsSearch['Date']." | ".$row_rsSearch['Room']." | ".$row_rsSearch['Period'];
} while($row_rsSearch = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSearch));
```